# Regarding REST and ColdFusion

Tags: rest, coldfusion, railo, cfml

I am having trouble describing to myself the method used for client/server interaction.

When I make AJAX calls, I use the `?name=value&name=value` query string approach. These query string parameters are then tossed into the URL structure in `ColdFusion`. What method is ColdFusion using to process these parameters? What would this client/server interaction be called?

It seems to me like REST uses the `/name/{value}/` approach, almost looks like a URL rewrite that hides the extension, and uses the Application.cfc to monitor HTTP verbs.

This might be totally missing the picture, but when I think of REST I come to:

Regular Way: `mySite.com/MyCFC.cfc?name=value&name=value`

REST: `mySite.com/users/name/{value}/`

Comment: *"What method is ColdFusion using to process these parameters?"* - I don't understand that question. *"What would this client/server interaction be called?"* - I'd call it an HTTP request. REST is not about the format of the URL, but about the architecture of the application *behind* the URLs. REST uses standard HTTP requests that are in no way special or different. The querystring-less approach is merely the widely adopted convention, not a hard requirement.

Comment: No. The default is plain text marked as `text/html`. For CFCs it depends on what your `returntype` and `returnformat` settings are for the function that has been called.

Answer (score 1):

If the REST web service specifies you make requests to to via a URL formatted as `mySite.com/users/name/{value}/`, then... that's what you request. I'm not *entirely* sure how that's not immediately clear? I'm not being obtuse... I don't see how there's more than one way to interpret that.

On the ColdFusion end of things, one adds annotations to a CFC and its methods to identify which methods respond to which verbs and combinations of query strings, body content, headers, and path fragments (as per your examples).

All of this is fairly thoroughly covered in the docs: [RESTful Web Services in ColdFusion](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/RESTful+Web+Services+in+ColdFusion).

You could probably circumvent most of your questions by reading those docs thoroughly, and experimenting, first.

Comment: So in conclusion, REST is just a different way of processing the URL compared to the standard query string? Seems to me REST requires a lot more complexity... since the URL is non-standard, it would require a framework to parse the request... correct (unless using the ColdFusion built in way)?

Comment: *"REST is just a different way of processing the URL"* No, REST is a specific way of constructing an application interface. URL format is merely a convention.

Comment: So REST architecture monitors HTTP request verbs to launch whatever processing it is going to do. Does that mean the query string can use either the standard way, or the conventional way of writing a REST URL? I have a method in a CFC called 'update', but I pass in additional parameters to determine the processing (all on a standard query string). Would this be considered RESTful?

Comment: What REST is is fairly well explained via many documents Google knows about. Indeed the first match is a good explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer. I don't think many people here are going to be able to explain it better than that. Basically it's a return to the intent of the HTTP protocol: where docs are addressed via a URL path: `/user/adam` would be the record for the `adam` user. GETting it would return the data. DELETEing it would delete it, etc. That's all REST is, in a nutshell: a standardisation of URL and HTTP verb usage.